# Drupal 7, Update field when checkbox checked of specific content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

**Problem:**
Content type: News
Fields:
 - Title (Textbox) (Machine name: title)
 - Body (Textarea) (Machine name: body)
 - Logo (File) (Machine name: logo)
 - Featured (Checkbox) (Machine name: featured_news)

I need to show only one featured news ordered by changed date descending and other requirements.

**How to implement it?**
When someone checked the Featured field of one news then already checked other featured news should be unchecked.

**Here are my steps that I followed:**

- Made a module (newscheckbox)
- Made functions

```
function newscheckbox_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'MY_FORM_ID_REPLACE_WITH_UNDERSCORE') {
    $form['#submit'][]='featured_news_update';
  }
}

function featured_news_update(){
  $nodeid=getFeaturedNews();
  if($nodeid){
    nodeSaveNews($nodeid);
  }
}

function nodeSaveNews($nodeid){
  $node = node_load($nodeid); // 1 is node id we want to load
  $node->field_featured_news[$node->language][0]['value'] = '0';
  node_save($node);
}
```

Somehow it is working, but is there any other good way to achieve it.

Comment: What have you tried to get this working? It might help us better understand your issue and provide assistance.

Comment: Created content type "news" (Machine name: news) , added those fields.
Have not done anything in coding. As I am stuck how to implement.
Is there any hook to get those requirement?

Comment: @Henders just added some code now. Any suggestions to improve it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to display one news item why don't you create a view which displays new items that only have a checkbox checked (which you can create with the 'fields' module). Just seems a bit easier than writing custom code for this..